# Having trouble using the Fax printer to programmatically create tiff

Tags: vb.net, vb6

The below was an answer provided by user "Mike".   When I try the code in vb6 I get a corrupt tiff, when I try it in vb.net I get a 0 byte file.  Please help me understand what I may be missing...

You can convert a Word document to a TIFF programatically by utilizing the standard "Fax" driver that is supplied with Microsoft Windows. The key to this working is ensuring the OutputFileName has an extension of ".tiff" Here is the sample code (VB.net & Word 2010):

```
Dim objWdDoc As Word.Document
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim sDesktop As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"

objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(sDesktop & "testdocument.doc")
objWord.Visible = True

'Select Printer
objWord.ActivePrinter = "Fax"
'Print to Tiff
objWdDoc.PrintOut(Range:=WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument, _
                  OutputFileName:=sDesktop & "test.tiff", _
                  Item:=WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent, _
                  PrintToFile:=True)
'Close Document
objWdDoc.Close()
'Close Word
objWord.Quit()
'General Cleanup
objWdDoc = Nothing
objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: tracked this down to this line not working:
    `objWord.ActivePrinter = "Fax"`
when I set my default printer to Fax, it works
when I examine the objWord.ActivePrinter in this state it is: "Fax on NE02:"
however when I set the default printer back to normal and try:
    `objWord.ActivePrinter = "Fax on NE02:"`
that does not work either
still can't get this to work

Comment: OK, getting closer.  Looks like when you have a network printer as your default printer, the .ActivePrinter call does not work.  May need to use the windows api instead of the .ActivePrinter to set the correct printer.  I will post again if I find anything else on this.

Comment: got it working using the windows api to set the printer:
Private Declare Function SetDefaultPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
   Alias "SetDefaultPrinterA" _
  (ByVal pszPrinter As String) As Long

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't working because the default printer was set to a network printer and using .ActivePrinter won't change it from a network printer.
I solved this by using the windows api to set the default printer and I just set it back when done:

```
Private Declare Function SetDefaultPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
   Alias "SetDefaultPrinterA" _
  (ByVal pszPrinter As String) As Long
```